# Creating a PostgresSQL table using psycopg2 in Python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a remote PostgresSQL database using the `psycopg2` library in Python. To be clear, I can already do this using psql.exe, but that is not what I want to do here. So far, I have verified that I can connect and use my cursor to perform a simple query on an existing table:

```
 import psycopg2
 
 conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydb', user='postgres', password='mypassword', host='www.mydbserver.com', port='5432', sslmode='require')
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute('SELECT * FROM existing_schema.existing_table')
 one = cur.fetchone()
 print(one)
```

This essentially, connects to an existing schema and table and selecting everything. I then fetch the first row from `cur` and print it. Example output: `('090010100001', '09001', None, 'NO', None, 'NO')`. Now, I want to create a new table using this same method. I have already created a new schema called `test` within mydb. My plan is to copy csv data to the table leter, but for now, I just want to create the blank table. Here's what I have tried:

```
 cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE test.new_table
    (
        region TEXT,
        state TEXT,
        tier TEXT,
        v_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_total DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_total DOUBLE PRECISION
    )
""")
conn.commit()
```

When I ran the above in a Jupyter Notebook, I assumed it would be a rather quick process. However, it seems to get stuck and just run and run (the process did not complete after 30 + mins). Eventually, it threw an error: `OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.` Should it take that long to run this simple line of code?! (I'm guessing, no). What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Define stuck and 'run and run'? Have you used `psql` to see if the table is created?  Where are you running the code, in a script or a Python client e.g. `ipython`. Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: works for my once I fix the indentation and point it at my own server

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. The process did not complete for 30 + mins. I walked away for a while and when I came back it had thrown `OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.` I am running this in Jupyter Notebook(Anaconda) as a test before incorporating it into my larger script. @jjanes - as I mentioned, the database is running on remote server and I cannot use a local dB. What were the indentation issues?

Comment: The error message means a problem with the server. Most often it occurs when the server has a problem with loading one of its components (extensions), e.g. due to version incompatibility or mixing 32 and 64-bit libraries in Windows. Start by analyzing the server logs.

Comment: I would use `psql` to connect to the database using the same connection parameters you are using in the Jupyter notebook.  See if it works and if not what the errors are as returned to the client as well as in the Postgres log.

Comment: To be clear, I can already do this using psql.exe, but that is not what I want to do here. I am strictly looking for a psycopg2 solution in my Python script. However, if you have an answer that incorporates using psql.exe into a python script to allow me to create a new table and copy a csv to that table, please put your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is an issue with using the `.copy_from()` method in psycopg2. That was the issue. This is how I overcame it:

```
 conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydb', user='postgres', password='mypassword', host='www.mydbserver.com', port='5432', sslmode='require')
 cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE test.new_table
(
    region TEXT,
    state TEXT,
    tier TEXT,
    v_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
    v_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
    v_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
    v_total DOUBLE PRECISION,
    a_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
    a_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
    a_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
    a_total DOUBLE PRECISION
    )
""")
conn.commit()

with open(output_file, 'r') as f:
    next(f) # Skip the header row.
    #You must set the search_path to the desired schema beforehand
    cur.execute('SET search_path TO test, public')
    tbl = 'region_report_%s'% (report_type)
    cur.copy_from(f, tbl, sep=',')

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```